# How can I find out the value of an Eclipse path variable or string variable ( `${some_var}` )?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, one can use so called "[path variables](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcpathvars.htm)" and so called "[string variables](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/run-debug/ref-string_substitution.htm)" at some places. For example, in a "run configuration", the base directory can be set to `${project_loc:/${project_name}}` instead of providing a static value.

How can I find out the value of such a variable (or the value of an expression consisting of possibly several variables)?

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't possible. The "Select Variable" dialog has a "Description" field - it should also have a "Value" field that shows...  the value.  Actually, I'd prefer it if the list of variables had a column that displays the value. Visual Studio does a decent enough job of this.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Project "Properties" dialog. On the left-side menu, expand "Resource" and click on "Linked Resource". This will should immediately show the defined "Path Variables" on the big right panel, including $project_loc$. Note you can also add new variables to your project.

Comment: This is already a good start for finding out, thanks! ... what about `${project_name}` and `${project_classpath}`. At least in my case, these variables are not listed under "Path Variables", yet they exist as variables in, for example, "Run Configurations" - but there I cannot see to what values these variables evaluate to.